# How should I start feeding an indoor plant after over a year's break?

Tags: indoors

I have three indoor plants that I haven’t fed for over a year, since I repotted them. They have some yellow leaves and aren’t looking as healthy as they could. I am going to start feeding them with a liquid plant food. The instructions say to use 7 drops for 1 qt (approx 1 L) of water. If I do this, will it take quite a while to build nitrogen levels in the soil before they recover, or will they start looking good quickly? Is there any advantage if I increase the concentration? Is there any advantage if I run lots of food-laden water through them, rather than just filling until it can’t take any more?

I usually water them once a week by watering them until water runs freely out the bottom. This has kept the plants in a pretty good state for around four years, apart from this yellowing.

Comment: Can you share a link to the brand of fertilizer you're using?

Comment: Less is more when it comes to fertilizer! Fertilizer IS NOT FOOD! Nutrients are needed to help the plant make its own food.  Be patient, add Osmocote 14-14-14.  It lasts for 4 months.  Follow the directions...grin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your watering regime sounds just fine, though you haven't said which plants they are. I wouldn't recommend you increase the dosage, just feed regularly, but it might be worth checking that these plants don't need potting up again, perhaps the yellowing is as much to do with being rootbound as lack of nutrients, unless they're acid lovers and growing in alkaline conditions.